# Removing $\exists, \iff, \lor $ in $\forall v_1\forall v_2 \exists v_3\forall v_4(\in v_4v_3 \iff v_4=v_1 \lor v_4=v_2)$

Tags: logic

The expression "given 2 sets, there exists one set such that the elements are exactly the given sets"  is translated, in set theory, as:

$$\forall v_1\forall v_2 \exists v_3\forall v_4(\in v_4v_3 \iff v_4=v_1 \lor v_4=v_2)$$

I'm trying to eliminate $\exists, \iff$ and $\lor$ in the expression above. I know that I must find equivalences between connectives, but my book didn't give any. How should I do? I know, for example, that $p \iff q$ is equivalent to $p \mbox{and}  q$. So it should be $v_4v_3\iff v_4$ be translated to $v_4v_3 \mbox{and} v_4$? What about the others?

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate logical connectives? What's the point?

Comment: Because the exercise asks me to do it :c

Comment: You cannot eliminate the $\exists$ really, only via de duality with $\forall$ maybe. $\exists x \phi(x)$ is equivalent to $\lnot \forall x \lnot \phi(x)$

Comment: $p \Leftrightarrow q$ is equivalent to $(p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$.

Comment: $p \implies q$ is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor  q$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You can eliminate them through quantifier elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula here is
$$\forall v_1 \; \forall v_2 \; \exists v_3 \; \forall v_4 \; (v_4 \in v_3 \; \leftrightarrow \; v_4 = v_1 \lor v_4 = v_2)$$
First, we note every universal quantifier can be replaced as follows
$$\vdash \; \forall v \, \varphi \; \leftrightarrow \; \lnot \exists v \, \lnot \varphi \tag{$\top^{1}$}$$
Baring in mind that this applies only to Prenex Normal Form (**PNF**) formulae, but it is logically true that every formulae can be formed in **PNF**. Lets flip all the universals
$$(\lnot)\exists v_1 \; (\lnot)\exists v_2 \; \exists v_3 \; (\lnot)\exists v_4 \; (v_4 \in v_3 \; \leftrightarrow \; v_4 = v_1 \lor v_4 = v_2)$$
Now, as you may know that every formula can be formed in Disjunctive Normal Form (**DNF**), by the *quantifier elimination theorem*$^{2}$, we can turn it into an all quantifier free formula, and to get rid of the '$\lor$' in the RHS we can rewrite it using *De Morgan's Laws*$^{3}$ into
$$\lnot(\lnot(v_4 = v_1) \; \land \; \lnot(v_4 = v_2))$$
As for the '$\leftrightarrow$', we can re-write it into
$$(v_4 \in v_3 \; \to \; \lnot(\lnot(v_4 = v_1) \; \land \; \lnot(v_4 = v_2))) \; \land \; (\lnot(\lnot(v_4 = v_1) \; \land \; \lnot(v_4 = v_2)) \; \to \; v_4 \in v_3)$$
At the end it will be equivalent to some formula such that
$$\psi \; \equiv \; (\phi_1 \; \land \; \phi_2 \; \land \; \phi_3 \; \land \; \phi_4)$$
Such a formula will be quantifier-free and doing this, it completes all the requirements by removing the quantifiers, and proving that it is possible to remove the *if and only if* operator as it simply a shortcut for $(p \to q) \; \land \; (q \to p)$, and that *or* operator using *De Morgan's Laws*.

---

*Footnotes:*
1: $\top$ is used to indicate a tautology (universally [logically] true).
2: It states that for a theory $\mathbf{\phi}$ in a language $\mathcal{L}$, the following is true:
\begin{align}
\text{If $\phi$ is an atomic $\mathcal{L}$-formula, then $\lnot \varphi$ is logically equivalent to a disjunction of conjunctives of atomic $\mathcal{L}$-formulae}\\
\text{For every $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\varphi$, there will exist another $\mathcal{L}$-formula such that $\varphi \; \equiv \; \exists v \; (\phi_1 \; \land \; \cdots \; \land \; \phi_n)$, and each $\varphi_{[1, n]}$ an atomic $\mathcal{L}$-formula}\\ 
\text{There will exist a quantifier-free $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\psi$ where $\mathbf{\phi} \vdash \phi \, \leftrightarrow \, \psi$ and free($\psi$) = free($\varphi$)${\setminus}$$\{v\}$}
\end{align}
Repeating the process of turning the formulae into **DNF**, and then applying the tautology finitely many times will result in a quantifier-free formally as promised by the theorem.
3: $\lnot (p \; \lor \; q) \; \iff \; (\lnot p \; \land \; \lnot q)$, and the vice versa $\lnot (p \; \land \; q) \; \iff \; (\lnot p \; \lor \; \lnot q)$.

Hope that answered your question, and made you understand the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say (it's the pairing axiom):

$$\forall v_1, v_2 \exists v_3: v_1 \in v_3 \land v_2 \in v_3 \land (\forall x \in v_3: x = v_1 \lor x= v_2)$$
which is the same as (if you don't like bounded quantification):

$$\forall v_1, v_2 \exists v_3: v_1 \in v_3 \land v_2 \in v_3 \land (\forall x : ((x \in v_3) \implies (x = v_1 \lor x= v_2))$$

Comment: How did you arrive at this?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs isn't it clear? It's just logic :)

Comment: You can eliminate $\lor$ using de Morgan: $\phi \lor \psi$ is equivalent to $\lnot(\lnot \phi \land \lnot\psi)$. That's boring.

Comment: This is wrong, the person wants to get rid of the quantifier, and not the correct application of quantifier elimination (if at all).

Comment: Also, please try to use **PNF**. Much easier to read.